# Sectional curvature in complex manifold

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a Hermitian manifold .Say that the sectional curvature of X is negative is the same to say that the sectional curvature of the Hermitian metric $\omega$ is negative, otherwise, what is the difference between the sectional curvature of a complex manifold and the sectional curvature of the Hermitian metric. Because I see that the sectional curvature is dependent only on the Riemannian metric not on the Hermitian metric.

Comment: A hermitian metric is indeed a Riemannian metric, so the sectional curvature of any 2-dimensional real subspace of the tangent space at a point has the same definition. However, since the tangent space has a complex structure, there are special 2–real-dimensional subspaces, notably the 1-complex-dimensional  subspaces. This is relevant when one talks about positive or negative curvature. In particular, positive holomorphic sectional curvature means the sectional curvature of any complex line is positive. This is a weaker condition than positive sectional curvature.